Why does the Torah add ger sometimes
For some commandments in the chumash the Torah adds "and also the ger with you", and sometimes it does not.
What's the reason for this? Is there a specific reason every time?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
